# PHP: read part of file with fread() from http resource

Tags: php, fread

I have the following PHP code:

```
$fp=fopen("http://myurl.com/very_big_file.txt",'r');
$feed=fread($fp,16);
```

It works correctly but I have some doubts. Does it really reads only first 16 bytes without downloading the whole file?

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to test, right? Just point it at a 700MB ISO, ask for 16 bytes and see if it takes more than a moment to run.

Comment: According to me it does download the whole file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> string fread ( resource $handle , int $length )

fread() reads up to length bytes from the file pointer referenced by handle. Reading stops as soon as one of the following conditions is met:

1. length bytes have been read
2. EOF (end of file) is reached
3. a packet becomes available or the socket timeout occurs (for network streams) <-- this line says it.
4. if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size.